# I want to load non-vue assets (json) generated by the server using webpack and vue

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-router

I am largely following https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-single-page-time-tracking-app-with-vue-js-part-ii to create a basic vue app. But as part of that app I would like to return dynamic assets from the server, namely I want to serve up api results. These results will actually be generated by loading one large json file, but on the client side only serving up pieces of that file based on the path.

Essentially while using the vue router I want to be able to have paths such as "/api/years/2000" that return json containing the data that matches with 2000. As configured, outside of static assets, everything returns the single page vue.

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON data structure? What you want is possible with Vue router, you would just map a route with parameters to a component.

Comment: It is currently a 30mb file. It will probably go into some sort of DB at a point, but I want to avoid loading the entire thing on the client site which, I believe, is what will happen if I load it with Vue router. Instead, I would like to load it server side and manipulate it to only return the relevant pieces on the client side.

Comment: What you're looking for is simply a REST API which serves your data according to route structures you define.

Using Vue.js in this case is really just a detail. I would create a separate project for your API and then make requests to it with Vue Resource or another XHR library.

You can map your Vue routes to the requests which go to your API so that you can pull out the particular pieces of data for the client-side route you want.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. ;) I'm learning node/webpack/etc as it is, was trying to avoid two separate projects, but I will look at taking that approach.